# Is it possible to export a single object from an entire scene?

Tags: objects, export, scene

In a scene with more than one object, is it possible to export that one object without deleting every other object, exporting it, then undoing the deletes?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes , most exporters have the option to only export selected objects.

[image]

You can find this option under `File -> Export -> <your exporter>`, e.g. `STL` or `OBJ`. The relevant checkbox is "Selection Only".