# Export select pieces of a model?

Tags: modeling

I was wondering of there was a way to export a piece of the model instead of having to delete everything in the scene and then saving it and then undeleting everything again? Kind of like a select export.

[image]

Comment: This has been asked countless times before http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55913/is-it-possible-to-export-a-single-object-from-an-entire-scene/55915#55915 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56800/can-you-export-stl-file-from-one-object-in-one-layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After selecting the objects you want, go to File -> Export. In the bottom left corner, you'll see a panel labeled "Export [name of file type]". There, you can click a checkbox labeled either "Selected Objects" or "Selected Only". The .ply, .stl, and .bvh files don't have these options. For example, here's the "Selected Objects" checkbox when you export to .fbx.

[image]